# What do the symbols '+', and '?' when referenced from resource definition signify?

Tags: android, android-layout

Just got started w/Android on my Win 7 box after a hiatus following my first attempt.

In playing with the XML layout I see that the referencing convention defined are of the following forms

- @[+][package:]type:name
- ?[package:][type:]name

I know name is probably the identifier for the resource referenced, and the rest of each string is probably a qualifier E.g. @+id/myTextView

Here, myTextView is a name defined in another file in the same package (I think)

Specifically, what do the symbols '+', and '?' signify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Android's [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html):

> The at-symbol (@) at the beginning of
>   the string indicates that the XML
>   parser should parse and expand the
>   rest of the ID string and identify it
>   as an ID resource.
>
> The plus-symbol (+) means that this is
>   a new resource name that must be
>   created and added to our resources (in
>   the R.java file)

Comment: Thanks. I missed that in the docs; not part of the downloaded docs, is it?

Answer (score 1):

just look at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html